# how sencha get data from event

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a list in my view declare listeners on it. How can I get the record data from the event `"itemdoubletap"`?

My code in view:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    flex: 1,                            
    store: 'loanliststore',
    itemTpl: '贷款名：{loanname}，描述：{loandesc}',

    listeners: {
        itemdoubletap: function(index, target, record, e, eOpts){
            console.log(record.get('loanname'));
            //the console said cant read the property 'get'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an argument, change:

```
function(index, target, record, e, eOpts)
```

To:

```
function(cmp, index, target, record, e, eOpts)
```

Comment: can i ask you a question.why cmp is worked, but instead of this, the console tell error.THX

Comment: `this` is a reserved keyword in javascript.